# how can i change product price according to buy price on Odoo 11?

Tags: odoo

I'd like to change sale prices according to buy prices, but I can't seem to find the way to do so, how can I proceed?

I have been stuck with this problem for a week now.

Comment: Welcome to SO. You need to tell us what you have tried so far. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for guidance.

Comment: Thanks! 

Everything, I have activated all options that i see from "activate landed costs" to "Prices computed from formulas (discounts, margins, roundings)" tarification for both sales and buys, and nothing, the price still doesn't change, but none seem to work.

Comment: For example if product a costs 100 a unit, we buy one, and then get another unit for free, the price for the client should be 50 OR 100, but it always raises 0

Answer (score 0):

I'm leaving this for reference in case someone needs it in the future:

You just have to activate automatic inventory valuation in the product category which you want to have automatic price calculation.